# commit calender not in sync with PC time

Tags: git, github, time, system-clock

The commit calendar in https://github.com/ is not in sync with my PC clock. my PC clock is showing the right time.

if in my PC clock its 2nd of April and I contribute something it shows that i have contributed it on 1st of April .

This is being happening for 2 or 3 days now.

I have tried manually syncing the UTC time zone on my computer but still that did not resolve my issue.

I am on windows10.

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried manually syncing the UTC time zone on my computer but still that did not resolve my issue.

Then try to log out of github.com, then log back in and see if Github still show an incorrect time. It should be based on your local system configuration.
On my repository, I do see UTC+2, which is the right timezone for me.

Comment: I did that still no success , the time shown on my PC is right

Comment: So when you do a git log, you would see the right time shift (+2 in my case: `Sat, 10 Jul 2021 16:56:20 +0200`)?